# Looping Through a grid for temperature but don't know how to tell program to stop looping

Tags: c++, loops, iteration, visualization

I have assigned variables from an input file and am trying to output them to a file to run a program to show the heat distribution on a plate. The program loops through each sensor on the plate and calculates the temperature. The program should stop when the maximum and minimum temperature are uniform. How do I get the outer while loop to recognize the maximum and minimum values and loop until they're approximately the same?

```
 while ((maxTemp - minTemp)>0.1)
{
    fout << "VARIABLES = 'X' 'Y' 'T' " << endl;
    fout << "ZONE I = " << xSensor << " J = " << ySensor
         << " SOLUTION TIME = " << time << "F=POINT" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < xSensor - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ySensor - 1; j++)
        {
            x = i * l/(xSensor - 1);
            y = j * l/(ySensor - 1);
            part1 = exp((-2* (pi * pi) * alpha * time )/(l * l));
            part2 = sin((pi * x)/l)*sin((pi * y)/h);
            temperature = To + Tm * part1 * part2;

            if (temperature < minTemp)
            {
                minTemp = temperature;
            }

            if (temperature > maxTemp)
            {
                maxTemp = temperature;
            }

            fout << x << " " << y << " " << temperature << endl;

        }

    }

    time ++;

}
```

Comment: Recommend crafting a [mcve] and updating the question if crafting the MCVE doesn't show you the solution your problem. Have you ensure that `maxTemp` and `minTemp` have reasonable values that can be used to start the process when entering the loop?

Answer (score 0):

From your description you want min and max to be the minimum and maximum from that particular iteration of the loop, but what you are actually computing is the overall minimum and maximum across all iterations (how are the overall values supposed to converge together? once they record some extreme value, they will be stuck at it). You need to reinitialize min and max at the start of each loop and probably put the test at the end as a *do while* loop instead.